# Find explicit formula for summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I have this summation: $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} 2^{i}$, any suggestion of how get an explicit formula?

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$ as the upper limit of the sum, the closed form is simply $2\cdot\dfrac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}-1}{2-1}=2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor+1}-2$

Comment: @egarro: this is elementary. Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} 2^{i}&=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^{i}\tag{1}\\
> &=2\frac{1-2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}}{1-2}\tag{2}\\
> &=2\left(2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}-1\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> In the special case $n=2^k$ the formula simplifies to $2^{k+1}-2$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we note that the index range of the sum are integer values. So, the upper limit is the greatest integer less or equal to $\log_2 n$. This can be denoted with  the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* $\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$.
- In (2) we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^{n}a^i=a\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need $n$ to be a power of $2$ for for the sum to exist. For simplicity I'll write $\log_2 n=k$ and then you will get

$2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{k}$

And if you factor out $2^k$ you have $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ which is a geometric sum equal to $\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2^k-1}{2^k-2^{k-1}}$. Hope I didnt mess up that algebra but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming n is a power of 2, the formula will be $2n-2$.

Intuitively, if you have $2+4+8+16+32+...+n$, all of the numbers preceding n will add up to 2 less than n, so the sum will be $2n-2$.